# Linux script for Bluetooth operation

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, bluetooth, terminal

I want to automate bluetooth operation on my Ubuntu system.
Is there any script or application which I can use to perform basic Bluetooth operations like enable, discover, file transfer and disable.

Answer (score 2):

You can enable your bluetooth stick by running

```
$ hciconfig hciX up
```

where hciX is a bluetooth device name (e.g hci0)

To obtain a list of devices, just type

```
$ hciconfig -a
```

(http://linux.die.net/man/8/hciconfig)

With the BlueZ package installed, you can discover devices nearby using

```
$ hcitool inq
```

(http://linux.die.net/man/1/hcitool)

If you wish to use OBEX transfer (the protocol used while sending a file from a bt device to another), you should install the OpenOBEX package with which you may type

```
$ obexftp -b 00:11:22:33:44:55 --put /some/file/to.put
```

to send /some/file/to.put to the device with bt address 00:11:22:33:44:55
(http://linux.die.net/man/1/obexftp)

Finally, if you would like to disable your bluetooth adapter, just call

```
$ hcitool hciX down
```

**UPDATE**

The following packages should be installed on your system in order to have the commands listed above available. Some of them may involve kernel extensions (like additional modules).

- BlueZ (http://www.bluez.org/)
- OpenOBEX (http://sourceforge.net/projects/openobex/)

Regards